# Compare Postgresql timestamp to timezone in sql query in django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-timezone

When I run the following query

```
Viewed.objects.raw('SELECT "recently_viewed_viewed"."id"FROM "recently_viewed_viewed" WHERE NOT ("recently_viewed_viewed"."viewed_date" <= \'timezone.now()\' AND "recently_viewed_viewed"."user_id" = user_id)' )
```

I get

```
DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "timezone.now()"
```

I've been struggling with this one haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django expect `timestamp with time zone` But you pass `timestamp without time zone`. you must add `timezone` to your time or set `USE_TZ = False` in your `settings.py`.

you can use `pytz` for add `timezone` . or use this:

```
timezone.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_default_timezone())
```

for changing `timezone` with your setting timezone.

Comment: doesn't `timezone.now()` include the timezone though?

Comment: no, check `timezone.is_aware(timezone.now())` and see result.

Comment: okay can I just use pytz to convert it? I have `"viewed_date" <=  \'timezone.localtime(datetime.now(), is_dst=None)\'` now